# Cant write to internal HDD NTFS partition in Parrot OS

Tags: linux, mate-desktop

Im am having an error of "THE DESTINATION IS READ ONLY" in my parrot OS when im trying to copy something in my internal NTFS partition.

My OS is based on [image: MATE]

and i tried to mount the NTFS partition manually , but now it shoes an error like this
[image: error]

Comment: The explanation is written very clearly in your second screen. You wanted to mount an unclean NTFS filesystem, which the OS detected and refused to mount read/write in order to prevent dataloss. Please run a check on the HDD from Windows and try again.

Comment: @schaiba: Im not using windows . i have only one linux OS in my system

Comment: @schaiba: im new to linux , can u please say how to make an unclean NTFS filesystem as u mentioned ..?

Answer (score 1):

An NTFS being mounted read-only is usually caused by:

1. Windows using hybrid shutdown mode, which is turned on by default since Windows 8. To turn this off boot your Windows installlation, and under power management uncheck "Turn on Fast Startup", then shutdown. For more info, consider reading [this tutorial](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html)
   [image: Power Management Screen (Win10)]
2. The NTFS filesystem being incorrectly unmounted, like in an unclean shutdown. If this is the case, boot Windows and run a chkdsk in the volume, for example: `chdsk /x /r /f D:`. If the disk is currenly in use (ie. it's the boot disk), it will prompt you to reboot then it will start checking.
3. Your distro lacks the read/write driver for the NTFS filesystem, usually installing the ntfs-3g package allows you to do write to Windows partitions.

If you still can't mount the filesystem, you can try running the [ntfsfix(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsfix) utility as a last resort: `ntfsfix /dev/sdb2`, where `/dev/sdb2` is the NTFS volume in question. Beware this might cause data loss, and it's not a 'linux port' of Windows' chkdsk.exe

Answer (score 0):

Atlast i i booted with live HIRENS BOOT CD and deleted all pagesys files, SystemVolumeInformation folder ,$recyclerbin folder. then i tried booting with linux. NOw it works usual.